# Using object-fit: cover; doesn’t always yield the expected result in a container with an aspect ratio

Tags: css, svg, css-grid, aspect-ratio

I’m trying to use `object-fit` and `object-position` on an `<img />` element inside of a container with a specific aspect ratio. There are a lot of ways to approach applying an aspect-ratio to an element with CSS. The padding trick is the most popular, but I don’t want to use `position: absolute;` on the child image because I need the image to be smarter about its position and sizing. I basically need to emulate `background-size: cover;` with an `<img />` element that isn’t a background image. I could use `aspect-ratio`, but it’s barely supported.

I found [this really interesting technique](https://codepen.io/noamr/pen/mpamVN) for applying an aspect ratio to an element and it works for the most part. You can manipulate the aspect ratio by tweaking the `viewBox` values in the SVG. I’ve applied several aspect ratios to the `<picture />` and most work. `<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" />` clips the right and left sides of the child image as expected. `<svg viewBox="0 0 3 2" />` shows the entire image, uncropped. Cool.

However, when I use something like `<svg viewBox="0 0 3 1" />` the SVG is sized correctly, but the `<picture />` size isn’t correct, and the `<img />` isn’t being cropped at the top and bottom as expected.

Any idea why?

```css
.Picture {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px red;
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50vw;
}

.Picture > * {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.Img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<picture class="Picture">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 3 1" />
  <source media="(min-width: 1600px)" srcset="http://res.cloudinary.com/fringe/image/upload/f_auto/samples/people/bicycle.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="http://res.cloudinary.com/fringe/image/upload/f_auto/test/1950-1300.jpg">
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/fringe/image/upload/f_auto/test/1950-1300.jpg" class="Img">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all the elements are in-flow, the biggest will define the size and in your case it's not the SVG. To make sure the SVG is the only one that will define the size use `height:0;min-height:100%` on the image. This will make the image to not contribute to the height of grid and at the same time will force it to have full height.

```css
.Picture {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px red;
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50vw;
}

.Picture>* {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.Img {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<picture class="Picture">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 3 1" />
  <source media="(min-width: 1600px)" srcset="http://res.cloudinary.com/fringe/image/upload/f_auto/samples/people/bicycle.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="http://res.cloudinary.com/fringe/image/upload/f_auto/test/1950-1300.jpg">
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/fringe/image/upload/f_auto/test/1950-1300.jpg" class="Img">
</picture>
```